# How to filter views in Drupal on current user (not author)

Tags: drupal, view

I am a relatively noobe on Drupal and I have hit a problem with Views that I've not been able to resolve by Googling and reading similar questions here.

I have ten pages in a content type "Book".  I want to encourage users to read all of ten pages.  My intention was to create a View that listed specifically for each user which pages they had opened.

I can create a View and produce a list of the pages.
I can filter the list on Content statistics: Total views (>= 1) to produce a list of pages that have been opened.
--- So far this works predictably and produces the same correct list for three roles: admin, anonymous and logged in user.

My difficulty is setting up the filter for current user. I am aware that the filter for current user does not come up until a relationship is set up.  I have not been able to figure out the correct relationship to make a simple logged in user appear in the filter without being attached to author.

For further clarification, if it is relevant, the content type is the default book content type.

I would be grateful if anyone could steer me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the content statistics (Total views) keeps a count PER user.

Is there a statistic for instance "visited pages" for users. Because you could match that url with the current url.

Comment: Thanks - I had wondered if my problem was there. Will pursue that.